# I want to show an image in an ext.js modal window on click of an image

Tags: extjs, modal-dialog

I have a file which is processed via xls and converted to HTML and rendered to Extjs. My problem is image links are in xls  . On click of the image i am able not able to see the image because its iamge URL didnt called via function call.

How can i get it?
Here is my code--

Extjs:-

```
var showModal = function(url){   
    var previewWindow = new Ext.Window({
        modal:true,
        border:false,
        plain:true,
        width:500,
        height:500,
        constrain:true,
         html:'<div style="width:500px;height:500px;"><img src="url"></div>',
        resizable:{preserveAspectRatio: true}
    });
    previewWindow.show();
};
```

Xls code:-

```
  <xsl:when test="@align='left'">
    <div class="imageleft">
        <img width="{$image_width}" height="{$image_height}"
          class="image" src="vll/getImage?resource={$image_ref}" 
          onClick="showModal('vll/getImage?resource={$image_ref}')" >
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </img>
    </div>
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in syntax highlighting, you are not using the variable, but the string "url". Try the following:

```
html:'<div style="width:500px;height:500px;"><img src="'+url+'"></div>',
```

and get an editor with syntax highlighting, for instance `Notepad++` (which also has other features that are useful in ExtJS development, like search & replace in directory).